# Retrieve a text value in table with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have this html (with Razor to display rows in table) :

```
            @foreach (var item in Model.AllGroups)
            {
                <tr class="group-row" data-id="@item.Id">
                    <td class="align-middle text-primary">
                        <h4 class="group-name" > @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Name)</h4>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a class="btn btn-small btn-primary detail-group-btn">
                            <i class="fas fa-user text-white"></i>
                        </a>
                        <a class="btn btn-small btn-secondary edit-group-btn">
                            <i class="fa fa-edit text-primary"></i>
                        </a>
                        <a class="btn btn-small btn-danger delete-group-btn">
                            <i class="fa fa-trash text-white bg-"></i>
                        </a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
```

I bind a click event on the `delete-group-btn` button and when I click I want to retrieve the text value of `<H4>` tag.

At this step I'm doing it like that :

```
$(this).closest('.group-row').find('.group-name').text()
```

I works but I'm not sure it is the right and optimized way.

Is there a better solution?

Comment: If `h4` is the only one in your `<tr>`, you could use directly tags without class names. Something like this: `$("h4", $(this).closest("tr")).text();`

Comment: I don't know Jquery enough, but I think it's the best solution in term of peformance (it won't search the whole DOM this way), but in term of readibilty...

Comment: What you are doing is fine

Answer (score 1):

Since you probably have multiple rows (because of running foreach) you could assign a unique id to h4 element in each row.

For example id="h4_0" for h4 element in first row, id="ht_1" for h4 element in second row, ...

Then you can add "onclick" attribute to each button which calls certain function with row index as a parameter. In that function you combine row index with
 "h4_" and you have an id of h4 element in the same row.

Example for first row:

```
<h4 class="group-name" id="h4_0" > @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Name)</h4>


<a class="btn btn-small btn-danger delete-group-btn" onclick="doSomething(0)">

<script>
    function doSomething(rowIndex) {
        var h4Id = "h4_" + rowIndex;
        // Do something ...
    }
</script>
```

This is not the best solution but it also works :)

Comment: Using an ID is a good idea, but the attribute "onclick" is not as good.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but as said by Daniele, I don't want to hardcode the onclick event

Answer (score 1):

I'd add the id to a "data-target" attribute, something like this:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.AllGroups)
        {
            <tr class="group-row" data-id="@item.Id">
                <td class="align-middle text-primary">
                    <h4 class="group-name" id="@item.Id"> @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Name)</h4>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a class="btn btn-small btn-primary detail-group-btn">
                        <i class="fas fa-user text-white"></i>
                    </a>
                    <a class="btn btn-small btn-secondary edit-group-btn">
                        <i class="fa fa-edit text-primary"></i>
                    </a>
                    <a class="btn btn-small btn-danger delete-group-btn" data-target="@item.Id">
                        <i class="fa fa-trash text-white bg-"></i>
                    </a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
```

To be retrieved like this:

```
$( '#' + $(this).data('target') ).text();
```

Comment: Interesting pattern, I will have a look